# Can't connect to phone network, banned?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, connection-issues, mobile-network

I need a sanity check here. I was sitting on the train listening to music over 3G, and we went in to a tunnel. Lost the signal, tried to reconnect and couldn't. Now I can't connect to my phone service at all, even though

1) I have a strong signal

2) I can see my phone service in the list of available networks.

When I try selecting the network, it says it's not available to connect, and that I should try later. The thing is, my coworkers have similiar service and phones, and their works.

My question is; can the service ban my specific phone from connecting?

Comment: Stupid question, but have you rebooted?  I've had similar issues with network and with WiFi, but a reboot has always fixed it so far.

Answer (score 3):

The basic test you should do is to just switch the SIM card: have a coworker of yours try their sim in your phone, or try your sim in their phone, and see if it works. If your sim can not log into the network on a different phone, you should contact your phone company for explanation. On the other hand, if it is your phone, then you should look into that.